# Edit xml file code in textarea with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, textarea

Any ideas how to print some fragment of xml code into text area for modifying, then save the file with changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as any other bit of text.

Run it through `htmlspecialchars`, echo it out between the start and end tags of the textarea, then read it back from `$_POST` when the form is submitted.